# Dynamically generated regex for gsub not working

Tags: regex, awk, gsub

I have an input CSV file:

```
1,5,1  
1,6,2  
1,5,3  
1,7,4  
1,5,5  
1,6,6  
1,6,7
```

I need to create a string out of this as follows:

```
;5,1,3,5;6,2,6,7;7,4
```

So each character, except the first which is the value of the field `$2`, in the substring in between the `;` denotes the row number of middle field; for example `;5,1,3,5` means that `5` is at row number `1,3,5`.

I've been trying to use awk with `gsub`, trying to create the string `MYSTR` dynamically.

The regex inside the `gsub` is not working. I need a regex that will match `;$3` (the value of `$3`, which can be a two digit number) and replace it with `;$3,RowNO`, if the pattern is not matched then add `;$3` at the end of the string.

This is what I have so far:

```
awk -F',' '{
    print NR, $3;
    noofchars=gsub(/;$3/,";"$3","NR,MYSTR);
    print noofchars;
    if  ( noofchars == 1 )
        ;
    else
        MYSTR=MYSTR";"$3","NR;
    print NR, $3;
    print MYSTR;
}

END{print MYSTR;}' $1
```

Comment: I've edited your question a little. You should specify what "not working" means: what happens? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The regex doesn't work because `$3` isn't interpreted as the field #3 value but is seen as the anchor `$` *(that matches the end of the line)* and a literal `3`.

You can do it without `gsub`:

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]=a[$2]","NR}END{for (i in a){printf(";%d%s",i,a[i])}}'
```

Comment: The above awk code did not work for me, did not understand it completely.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$ cat file
1,5,1  
1,6,2  
1,5,3  
1,7,4  
1,5,5  
1,6,6  
1,6,7
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F, '{gsub(/[ ]+/,"",$3);a[$2] = ($2 in a ? a[$2]:$2) FS $3 }END{for(i in a)printf("%s%s",";",a[i]); print ""}' file
;5,1,3,5;6,2,6,7;7,4
```

**Better Readable version**

```
awk -F, '
         {
           gsub(/[ ]+/,"",$3);                     # suppress space char in third field          
           a[$2] = ($2 in a ? a[$2]:$2) FS $3      # array a where index being field2 and value will be field3, if index exists before append string with existing value 
         }
      END{             
           for(i in a)                             # loop through array a and print values
                  printf("%s%s",";",a[i]); 
           print ""
         }
        ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

@vsshekhar: Try following too: It will provide you values in the correct same order which Input_file ($2) are coming.

```
awk -F, '{A[++i]=$2;B[A[i]]=B[A[i]]?B[A[i]] "," FNR:FNR} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){if(B[A[j]]){printf(";%s,%s",A[j],B[A[j]]);delete B[A[j]]}};print ""}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, '{
                A[++i]=$2;
                B[A[i]]=B[A[i]]?B[A[i]] "," FNR:FNR
         }
                END{
                        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                                                if(B[A[j]]){
                                                                printf(";%s,%s",A[j],B[A[j]]);
                                                                delete B[A[j]]
                                                           }
                                         };
                        print ""
                   }
        '   Input_file
```